# Rendering PDF to image with PDFBox properly

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

So, in this application we're using iText to fill out PDF forms and PDFBox to load that filled out PDF and convert to image into our system.

The problem is when the image is converted. All the information is there, but the checkboxes are... weird? Instead of the styled checkbox "check mark" that is set on the PDF, the checkboxes get a weird "empty box" inside of them.

[image]

How it is supposed to be:

[image]

PDFBox version 2.0.11
iText version is 5.5.13

Here is a little snippet of the code where the conversion happens:

```
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(byteArrayInputStream);
PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(pdf);
BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[pdf.getNumberOfPages()];
PDPage page = null;
BufferedImage image = null;
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        try {
            image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, 300,org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType.RGB);
            ...
```

I'm kind of sensing a "loss of quality" too after the conversion. Before, we were using PDFBox 1.8 and the conversion quality was low and it was losing some font formatting and style. Since the upgrade it got better, but is still bugged.

Where the filling happens:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);

ByteArrayOutputStream lStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, lStr);
AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();

for (Entry<String, Item> map : acroFields.getFields().entrySet()) {
    String key = map.getKey();

    if (!fields.has(key))
        continue;

    if (fields.isNull(key))
        continue;

    acroFields.setField(key, fields.getString(key), true);
}
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);

stamper.close();
reader.close();

...
```

Do you guys know what this is?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the zapf dingbats or Microsoft Gothic font is installed. See also the log messages. And share the PDF if it still doesn't work.

Comment: In the "How it is supposed to be:" image, are the different background colors of "Alarme" and "Bancos de Cuoro" a different design or merely due to one of them having the focus?

Comment: @mkl I think is the latter. I clicked on "Alarme" and it was focused.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Interesting suggestion about the font because, when I run this application in a local machine, it generates the PDF just fine with the check marks and everything. But when we run on the server it is bugged. So I'd have to install these fonts in the JVM running the server, right? I will give a try, thanks.

Comment: My remark is only about PDFBox, i.e. the rendering. I don't know if itext needs the font to create the PDF. The font is one of the  "standard 14" fonts so it doesn't have to be embedded (unless it is PDF/A).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr hm... I see... But how would be the correct way to "import" a font into a PDF? With iText i managed to find the FontFactory class which has the register methods. Didn't work as expected. And with PDFBox: page.getResources().add(Font, file). The fonts (dingbat and ms gothic) are inside the resources folder. Got a bit confused here.

Comment: For PDFBox, just copy the missing font (if it is missing) the way your OS requires it. In windows, copy the zapf dingbats .pfb file in your \windows\fonts directory (or the msgothic.tt* file). There is no need to change your PDF file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Cool. I'm using linux and got different responses when I searched for the fonts root folder. Is it the /usr/share/fonts folder? Can I just drop that in there? Sorry for bothering.

Comment: segment from our code:   protected String[] getSearchableDirectories()
    {
        return new String[] { System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.fonts", // user
                "/usr/local/fonts", // local
                "/usr/local/share/fonts", // local shared
                "/usr/share/fonts", // system
                "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts" // X
        };
    }

Comment: So the easiest to test is to create a .fonts directory in your user directory and copy the font there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working thanks to Tilman Hausherr's suggestion. The problem was indeed the fonts missing in the server running the application. (Zapf Dingbats and/or MS Gothic).

Installing the missing fonts in a directory "./fonts" or "/usr/share/fonts" (Linux) / "/Windows/Fonts" (Windows) did the trick!

Comment: Nice that you added the solution as an answer! Can you now accept it, too?This helps others to see that it worked.